# If every non-trivial proper subgroup of $G$ is cyclic then is $G$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I know that the fundamental Fundamental Theorem of Cyclic Groups stats that if $G$ is cyclic then so is every subgroup. So if I am given a group $G$, then by demonstrating that every non-trivial proper subgroup is cyclic can I conclude that $G$ is cyclic?

I am inclined to say no. This is because the fundamental theorem is not an if and only if statement, but I cannot seem to come up with a counter example.

Comment: The smallest non-cyclic group (whatever it may be) must be a counterexample.

Comment: Indeed, searching in the smallest possible counterexample is a good technique to remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Klein four-group is a counterexample, as is the symmetric group on three elements.

Comment: Any group of order $p^2$ or $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers. I wonder where the OP was looking for counterexamples.

Comment: Any *non-cyclic* group of order $p^2$ or $pq$... ;-)  The question would be more interesting if $G$ is assumed to be infinite.

Comment: @Bungo Ouch. Too late to edit. I could delete it and post a correct comment but that would be cheating.

Comment: @bof No worries, it was clear what you meant.